# How to generate HMAC-SHA256 in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restful-authentication, sha256, hmac

How am I able to generate a HMAC-SHA256 signature in AngularJS?

I cant find any sources regarding this topic.

Comment: angular doesn't include a cryptography library.

Comment: Questions are required to show proof that you have attempted to solve the problem by yourself before you asked.

Comment: @JK: Stackoverflow is about helping each other and not bashing or accusing that someone is to lazy to find his/her own solution. We do not know the details. Just leave if you don't like the question. According to Your Profil: There are no stupid questions. Not to ask a question is stupid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AngularJS is javascript. So, you need to be asking: "How to generate hmac-sha256" in javascript. This has been [answered many times](https://www.google.com/search?q=hmac-sha256%20javascript).

For example using "jsSHA" you can do:

```
var shaObj = new jsSHA(hashType, "TEXT");
shaObj.setHMACKey("abc", "TEXT");
shaObj.update("This is a test");
var hmac = shaObj.getHMAC("HEX");
```